# How to get last two digit from a year which a user inputs

Tags: java, integer, stringbuilder

I Have been playing with this for while, and I can not seem to get my mind around how I can get this task accomplished.

**My task :**

I need get the last two digits of a year that a user has entered.

**Example :**

A user enters the July 2 , 2014; I need to get the last two digits of year 2014 which is "14" and divide it by 4. This will give me 3.5; however I will disregard the ".5" and just keep the 3.

**Research :**

I have been reading my Textbook, and seen one approach that I may be able to use which includes the string builder class.  However my book has a very brief description and shows no example which I can constructively use to accomplish me task.

**Progress:**

This is what I have so far, it is basically a template of how I want my program; I just need some help getting the last 2 digits of a year.

```
public class DateCalc

{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String month;
    int day;
    int year;
            Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

                // receiving input 
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Month Of The Date : ");
                month = keyboard.nextLine();
                // receiving input 
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Day Of The Date : ");
                day = keyboard.nextInt();
                // receiving input
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Year OF The Date : ");
                year = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch(month) 
        {  

              // keys are numbered indexes that I need for this, please disregard

            case "January" :
            int janKey = 1;
            break;


            case "February":  
            int febKey = 4;
            break;  


            case "March":  
            int marKey = 4;
            break;


            case "April":  
            int aprKey = 0; 
            break;

            case "May":  
            int maykey = 2; 
            break;

            case "June":  
            int junKey = 5; 
            break;

            case "July":  
            int julKey = 0; 
            break;

            case "August":  
            int augKey = 3; 
            break;

            case "September":  
            int septKey = 6; 
            break;

            case "October":  
            int octKey = 1; 
            break;

            case "November":  
            int novKey = 4; 
            break;

            case "December":  
            int decKey = 4; 
            break;

            //  IN MY DEFUALT CASE " inputValidation " WILL BE EXECUTED
            default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Invalid Entry Please Try Again " );

        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String date = "July 2 , 2013";
String year = ""+ date.charAt(date.length()-2) + date.charAt(date.length()-1);
System.out.println(year);

int year2 = Integer.parseInt(year);
System.out.println(year2);
```

Comment: You are awesome, this approach will be definitely do the job, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like `String yearString = Integer.toString(year).substring(2)`, which will first convert the integer to a string, then get the substring consisting of everything after the second character. Then to turn it back into an integer, try `int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(yearString)`

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the cleaner option would be to convert the day,month and year into a Calendar. And then get the two digit year from the calendar.

Something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, day);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy"); // Just the year, with 2 digits
String formattedDate = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is mod the year by 100 to get the last 2 digits. Then you can do whatever math you want with it.

This can be extended to get an arbitrary number of digits; modding a number by `10^n` yields the last `n` digits of the number.

Edit because I was stupid and thought `year` was a `String`